# One vertices and one edges in graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

Is a figure with only one vertices and one edge connected to that vertices known as a graph ?

Answer (score 1):

If that edge is a loop, yes. It is a [Multigraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigraph). Otherwise, it is not a graph.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say m it’s not a loop

Comment: Then that's not a graph. Simple graphs with non-empty edge sets need to have at least $2$ vertices.

Comment: Okay thanks , this also holds to subgraph right ?

Comment: Subgraphs are also graphs so yes. For instance, in a graph with $2$ vertices $x,y$ and an edge $xy$, we can't take a vertex $x$ and an edge $xy$ as a subgraph since it is not even a graph.

Answer (score 1):

With the strict definition of a simple graph, then there is no graph with one vertex and one edge. However, you **could** define a generalization of simple graphs which allows "half" edges with only one vertex and is **not** a loop. As far as the combinatorics, a half edge is no different than a loop, except in a path, it would be a dead end. However, in a drawing of the generalized graph on a surface, the loop would be closed curve, while a half edge would be be an open curve with only one of its endpoints to be considered a vertex. How useful this would be is not obvious to me now, but there is no reason why it could not have some useful purpose, just as graphs themselves have developed a great number of uses.

Comment: We could see it as half-edges too. The same way the configuration random graph model is built. Then introduce some matching between them...

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues Yes, thanks for your comment about half-edges!

Answer (score 0):

That is not a graph. A simple graph with one edge need to have at least 2 vertices.

Perhaps you meant this:

The graph $K_n$-clique is a graph in which all vertices are connected. Perhaps you want $K_2$.